# Large numbers Class, Initialisation

Tags: c++, biginteger

I am working on a class that deals with big numbers in C++.

Thing is I want it to be able to do a normal initialisation like:

```
Largeint A = 1934804692305674830675460730458673084576;
```

Instead of having to put the number between " ".

How should I go about achieving that?

***Edit due to comments:***

I know how to work with big numbers and do operations with them. The thing i was asking for is that i just don't want it too look like a string when giving it a value. Why? Just because.

And if integer literals are bound to the compiler settings, is there anyway i can go around this?

Both answeres are interesting and UDL are cool :D But, is there a way to use UDL without having to put a suffix at the end ?

Comment: Integer literals can be only defined in the range of integers the particular compiler can handle.

Comment: ...and what's wrong with a string?

Comment: @MitchWheat He may need to make arithmetic operations.

Comment: @ pranitkothari: yes, he can do that after initialisation. What's your point?

Comment: @MitchWheat If he makes it string, how can he make any mathematical operations on it?

Comment: are you serious? he uses the string value during construction to create the relevant large integer.

Comment: @MitchWheat Oh.. sorry, wrong interpretation of question. He already achieved things with strings.. my mistake.

Comment: C++11 has "User-defined literals" which may help you.

Comment: Yeah, a UDL is much better than a non-explicit conversion constructor from a string imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++11, we can make User-defined literals

```
Largeint operator "" _largeint(const char* literal_string)
{
    Largeint largeint;

    // initialize largeint with literal string content;
    return largeint;
}
```

or, if you prefer the variadic template

```
template<char... Cs> Largeint operator "" _largeint();
```

And then use it:

```
Largeint largeint = 123456789012345678901234567890_largeint;
```

You may use a more appropriate suffix name.

Comment: tried your code in Visual 2013, but it gives me some errors ( expects an operator and considers the word operator as a type ) I guess it has to do something with my compiler but i don't know.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx, User-defined literals is not yet supported with MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a macro like this:

```
#define MakeLargeint(VAR, N) Largeint VAR = #N;
```

and define `Largeint`s constructor to take a string.

So your line becomes:

```
MakeLargeint(A ,1934804692305674830675460730458673084576)
```

Comment: Interesting ideea but i wanted the = thinggy xD